# How should be the pricing using agile?

Tags: agile, sprint, pricing

How should be the pricing using agile?
Is it fixed per sprint?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to set it per sprint. That way, you can make sure the customer doesn't expect more than what is agreed in the sprint planning, and you can set the price based on the expected amount of work from known tasks.

It's not an axiom, so of course you can negotiate any alternatives that you are OK with.

Comment: I agree with Joanvo, going with a monthly retainer depending on the sprint length is a fair way to charge the client, and of course you need to promise a minimum number of business points to achieve as it will not be healthy to do a whole sprint for non-functional requirements only.


Just make sure to include the sprint, review & retrospective, so if the sprint is two weeks (10 working days) for 50 business point at least. Then you have 2 days for the review and retrospective meetings. The total of the retainer per month will be for 12 days to achieve at least 50 business points an costs $$$

Answer (score 1):

### Pricing is only one aspect of the contract

[Here is a good document that covers the contractual aspects of agile software development projects comprehensively.](https://www.twobirds.com/~/media/pdfs/brochures/contracting-for-agile-software-development-projects.pdf?la=en)

> How should be the pricing using agile? Is it fixed per sprint?

As you can see in the Pricing section, fixed price per sprint (iteration) is one option.

In the contract, you also need to cover other aspects such as Composition of the Development Team, Warranties and Indemnities, Termination, Intellectual Property Rights... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A common way would be T&M (time and material), basicly the customer knows how many people are involved in one sprint and how many hours they will work in one sprint. And Development just stops, when the budget is done at the end of a sprint. As you strive in agile to create the most value to the customer first, his project should be usable then already.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
Educate the client that they will be buying sprints as opposed to products. They will be given full visibility of work done in a sprint via reviews, sprint boards, and regular releases.

The cost of an agile sprint will be priced similarly to traditional projects. The catch is that the client buys a sprint at a time. The idea is that a strong client supplier relationship is built up through transparency.

Option 2
Price up what a sprint costs you, have a story mapping workshop to get a high-level view of the project and tender accordingly.

You may work out the price of a sprint and calculate how many sprints. Any changes from the original plan must be tracked and billed.

I hope these high level answers act as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I found a comprehensive explanation for the possible Agile pricing models in this website: https://agilecontracts.org/

Frankly, this is the only helpful resource I found about the topic.
It starts talking about the pricing and contract models in page 25 of the [PDF](https://agilecontracts.org/agile_contracts_primer.pdf) referenced in the website.